# apache on mod_wsgi Daemon Mode not yielding small string

Tags: mod-wsgi

While trying to test a few things, Using Django + apache2 + mod_wsgi3.3. I find two different results by running periodic yielding of results. Between embeded and daemon mode.

When tried with embedded mode, i.e having no WSGIDaemonProcess, WSGIProcessGroup directive used. below mentioned function yields results one after the other, with every digit getting printed on browser view after 2 seconds of sleep.

```
def yielder(request):
    gen = testYielding()
    return HttpResponse(gen)

def testYielding():
    yield "3"
    time.sleep(2)
    yield "4"
    time.sleep(2)
    yield "5"
    time.sleep(2)
    yield "6"
    time.sleep(2)
    yield "7"
```

Though with DaemonMode on, this view responds data after collating the complete response post 8 seconds with all the digits printed together and not yielding the same, one after the other.

Is this behavior correct? and is there a way to make sure on Daemon mode responses are yielded like embedded mode?

Answer (score 0):

The flush which occurs in the daemon process isn't transfered across to the Apache child worker process that is doing the proxying. Whether the output therefore is passed back through to the client immediately, will depend in part on what Apache output filters you have registered. If you have output filters which want to try and buffer up response data before flushing, you will see this issue.

You should therefore look closely at what Apache output filters are in place. If you can change these, then you would have no choice but to use embedded mode.